# C++ Object re-initialized after end of program

Tags: c++, object

Quick C++ question: So I'm doing some Raspberry Pi/Arduino stuff and everything is set up so I'm writing the code for the Raspberry Pi that controls the Arduino.
There's the picture of the code, and then there's the picture of the output. If you see in the code: The last line is "cout << "End Test" << endl;", but in the output, there's something else after that statement and that's the output that gets written when Decepticon is initialized (as you can see in the beginning of the output). Any idea why that's happening?

Here is the program code:

```
int main() {
  Decepticon d;
  cout << "Hello, World!"<< endl;
  //traverse(d);                                                                                    
  d.forward();
  //cout << "Start Test" << endl;                                                                   
  // cout << d->get_arduino_message() << endl;                                                      
  cout << "End Test" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the object code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "decepticon.hpp"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
//using namespace cv;                                                                               

/** Constructor                                                                                     
 */
Decepticon::Decepticon() {
    this->left_speed = 0;
    this->right_speed = 0;
    this->claw_pos = 0;
    //this->camera = raspiCamCvCreateCameraCapture(CAMERA_DEV);                                     
    serial_connect(&this->commlink, NULL, BAUDRATE, 0);
    if (this->commlink.connected){
      std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
      send_to_arduino();
    }
}

/** Deconstructor                                                                                   
 */
Decepticon::~Decepticon() {
  if (this->commlink.connected) {
    stop();
    serial_disconnect(&this->commlink);
  }
  // if (this->camera)                                                                              
  //raspiCamCvReleaseCapture(&this->camera);                                                        
}

/** Set the left-hand side speed                                                                    
 *  @param speed                                                                                    
 *    a value from -255 (full backward) to 255 (full forward)                                       
 */
void Decepticon::set_left(int speed) {
  this->left_speed = limit_signal(speed, -255, 255);
  send_to_arduino();
}

/** Set the right-hand side speed                                                                   
 *  @param speed                                                                                    
 *    a value from -255 (full backward) to 255 (full forward)                                       
 */
/** Make robot go full speed forward                                                                
 */
void Decepticon::forward() {
  this->left_speed = 255;
  std::cout << "left speed: " << this->left_speed << std::endl;
  this->right_speed = 255;
  send_to_arduino();
}

char *Decepticon::get_arduino_message() {
  char *message;
  message = serial_read(&this->commlink);
  if (strlen(message) == 0){
    std::cout << "message is NULL" << std::endl;
    return NULL;
  }
  return message;
}


void Decepticon::send_to_arduino() {
  int l, r, c;
  std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
  l = this->left_speed < 0 ? -this->left_speed + 255 : this->left_speed;
  std::cout << "l = " << l << std::endl;
  r = this->right_speed < 0 ? -this->right_speed + 255 : this->right_speed;
  c = this->claw_pos;
  sprintf(this->buf, "%03d%03d%03d\n", c, l, r);
  std::cout << this->buf << std::endl;
  serial_write(&this->commlink, this->buf);
  std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
/** Make the robot stop in place                                                                    
 */
void Decepticon::stop() {
  this->left_speed = 0;
  this->right_speed = 0;
  send_to_arduino();
}
```

Here is the Output:

```
Connected!
Start
l = 0
000000000

000000000
Write Succeeded
End
Hello, World!
left speed: 255
Start
l = 255
000255255

000255255
Write Succeeded
End
End Test
Start
l = 0
000000000

000000000
Write Succeeded
End
```

Comment: Please convert the image into source code.

Comment: Why not supply the source code necessary that includes the object definition

Comment: I agree with Ed Heal, this may have a bit to do with destructors

Comment: What's `Decepticon` looking like actually?

Comment: code added for Decepticon

Comment: This `this->` is not necessary

Comment: Where is the method `stop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost positive the `Decepticon` class has a destructor the prints out something. As soon as `d` goes out of scope, then something prints, however it's impossible to tell if it is exactly `d` who is printing something. A global variable, for example, may be an exception.

EDIT:

I now know that it is either

`stop();`

or

```
serial_disconnect(&this->commlink);
```

that is responsible for printing something, and am verified that it was indeed the destructor.

EDIT: If you want to stop extra messages to arduino, try commenting out the send call in the stop call in the destructor.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent the Destructor from being called?

Comment: Nooo, thee destructor is always called regardless whether or not you explicitly defined the function. It pushes data off the stack, or the heap. Go into `stop(); or serial_disconnect(&this->commlink);` if you really need to stop the excess printing.

Comment: its not the excess printing thats the problem, its that its sending unwanted data to the arduino...but I figured out how to stop it, I think.

Comment: I'm glad that you did, an upvote or acceptance check would show that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> The last line is "cout << "End Test" << endl;", but in the output, there's something else after that statement and that's the output that gets written when Decepticon is initalized (as you can see in the beginning of the output). Any idea why that's happening?

The destructor of `Decepticon` is called for `d` before returning from the function and after executing the last line of code in the function. If the destructor of `Decepticon` prints any messages they will be printed after the output of the last line of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The `Decepticon` destructor is calling `stop()` which in turn calls `send_to_arduino()`. *That* function is the one outputting the messages you see after your `main()` is done.

If you don't *want* that to happen, you will probably be best to modify the destructor so that it doesn't call that particular chain of functions.

Or, if you need the actual work done but no output generated, you could simply have a member variable called `echo` which is initialised to true in the constructor and set to false right at the start of the destructor. Then modify `send_to_arduino()` to be:

```
void Decepticon::send_to_arduino() {
  int l, r, c;
  if (echo) std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
  l = this->left_speed < 0 ? -this->left_speed + 255 : this->left_speed;
  if (echo) std::cout << "l = " << l << std::endl;
  r = this->right_speed < 0 ? -this->right_speed + 255 : this->right_speed;
  c = this->claw_pos;
  sprintf(this->buf, "%03d%03d%03d\n", c, l, r);
  if (echo) std::cout << this->buf << std::endl;
  serial_write(&this->commlink, this->buf);
  if (echo) std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

There are no doubt other ways to do this depending on your needs.

Comment: @user3140562, the update makes it look like something else is calling `send_to_arduino` and the likely culprit is `stop()` for which I see no code.

Comment: I added the code for stop...its right below send_to_arduino()

Comment: So is there anyway to prevent the destructor from being called?

Comment: @user3140562: destructors are called for a very good reason :-) But there are other ways to achieve what you want by simply modifying their behaviour - see the update for a couple.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the logic of the destructor

It calls `stop` which calls `send_to_arduino` etc. This is the extra output.

You could do this via a debugger